# Not all services loaded on Android

Tags: android

I am facing problem that not all services are running on Android.

I am trying to install Android 4.0 on ARM Development Board and load filesystem from mmc card.

I have done unyaffs for system.img, userdata.img and untar for ramdisk. I have copied content from ramdisk to mmc card, system.img content to /system on mmc and userdata.img to /data.

The shell booted successfully, I tried to run:

```
$service call SurfaceFlinger 10
$service call wallpaper 6 i32 1024 i32 768
$service call window 58
```

but I got errors:

```
service: Service SurfaceFlinger does not exist    
service: Service wallpaper does not exist    
service: Service window does not exist
```

I checked service list, an found that only 7 services are loaded:

```
$ service list    
Found 7 services:    
0       power: [android.os.IPowerManager]    
1       entropy: []    
2       sensorservice: [android.gui.SensorServer]    
3       media.audio_policy: [android.media.IAudioPolicyService]    
4       media.camera: [android.hardware.ICameraService]    
5       media.player: [android.media.IMediaPlayerService]    
6       media.audio_flinger: [android.media.IAudioFlinger]
```

When I checked for service list on Android Virtual Device emulator, I found that 50 services are running, including services SurfaceFlinger, wallpaper, window, and service call is executed successfully.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Considering that the Android 4.0 source code is not presently available, you really should be talking to the people from whom you "obtained" the source code.

Comment: Actually I obtained SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. While installing Android 2.3 on mmc I am facing the same problem.

Comment: The SDK is not designed to be "installed on ARM on mmc card".

Comment: I have Development Board on ARM processor. When I load filesystem over NFS Android works OK, but I want to load filesystem from mmc card.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK is not the full source, wait a few weeks for the source is the answer

Comment: Actually the same problem with services is on Android 2.3

Comment: sorry, my previous message concerning Android 2.3 was uncorrect. Actually I took images from SDK Android 2.2 and installed filesystem on mmc and it works successfully.

Comment: I still suggest using the real source, try it for 2.3 since that is available. can't help other than that

Comment: Thanks a lot for advice, dten. I will wait for Android 4.0 source code release and compile images.